# Evento Click. Exibir mensagem no form atual e abrir novo form

Tags: c#, winforms, eventos, click

Preciso fazer com que o evento click de um botão situado em um formulário, abra um outro formulário modal. Enquanto o outro formulário é carregado, preciso exibir ao usuário uma mensagem em uma StatusLabel de uma StatusStrip. (uma msg do tipo... Aguarde a configuração ser carregada...)

O comportamento que notei, é que a mensagem exibida ao usuário sempre é carregada depois que o formulário modal é aberto, operado pelo usuário e depois fechado. O evento de click segura para exibir a mensagem ao usuário até que a modal, do outro form, seja fechada.

Tentei utilizar uma BackgroundWorker dentro do evento de click, tanto para atualizar a UI com uma mensagem, quanto para tentar abrir o outro form modal, mas não deu certo.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    modelStatusLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 255, 192);
    modelStatusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    modelStatusLabel.Text = "Por favor aguarde a configuração ser carregada...";

    FormAddModel frmAddModelo = new FormAddModel(this, nameConfigFile);
    frmAddModelo.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Como posso fazer isto?

Obs: `modelStatusLabel` é um objeto do tipo `ToolStripStatusLabel`.

Comment: @Caffé, `modelStatusLabel` é um objeto do tipo `ToolStripStatusLabel`

Comment: @Caffé Obrigado. Perfeito funcionou. `statusStrip1.Refresh();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque seu aplicativo está ocupado abrindo o formulário e só vai processar as mensagens do Windows (por exemplo esta que manda escrever novo texto no componente) quando o aplicativo estiver disponível ("idle").

Você pode ordenar a repintura imediata do componente invocando seu método `Refresh()`.

Como o `ToolStripStatusLabel` não possui tal método, você pode colar este componente sobre um `StatusStrip` (caso ainda não esteja dessa maneira) e então invocar o método *refresh* do *StatusStrip*, já que este método ordena a repintura imediata não apenas do componente em si mas também dos seus componentes filhos.

O seu código ficaria assim:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    modelStatusLabel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 255, 192);
    modelStatusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    modelStatusLabel.Text = "Por favor aguarde a configuração ser carregada...";

    // considerando que modelStatusLabel seja um componente filho de statusStrip1,
    // o código abaixo fará o novo texto ser mostrado imediatamente.
    statusStrip1.Refresh();

    FormAddModel frmAddModelo = new FormAddModel(this, nameConfigFile);
    frmAddModelo.ShowDialog(this);
}
```